# Как создать свою альтернативу JavaScript(наподобии YoptaScript)?

Tags: javascript

мне сделать так, чтобы к примеру этот код:

```js
var i = 1;
alert (i);
```

выглядел в моем скрипте как:

```js
food i = 1;
eat (i);
```

Возможно ли это?

Comment: Все возможно.Только вот под силу ли вам ?

Comment: Лучше изучать уже существующие,это и мудро и полезно чем пустая трата времени.

Comment: Вы просто должны написать транслятор Вашего «языка» в JS. Пример посмотрите в репозитории вышеупомянутого проекта